# Django applications sharing databases on Heroku: set 'shared' database once for all

Tags: django, database, heroku

I have several Django applications and they need to share one database on Heroku. I may specify the shared database on each statement that need to access it, for example:

```
from account.models import User

if DEBUG:  # Running locally
    users = User.objects.all()  # 'default' DB
else:  # Running on Heroku
    users = User.objects.using('shared').all()  # 'shared' DB
```

I have two questions:

1) Specifying the `shared` database on every statement is really tedious. Is it possible to set the `shared` database once for all (maybe in `setting.py`)? For example:

```
from account.models import User

if not DEBUG:  # Running on Heroku
    User = User.objects.using('share')   # This is hypothetical!!

users = User.objects.all()
```

2) How do I set the `shared` DB for a foreign key. For example:

```
from account.models import User

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)  # How to set 'User' to come from 'shared' DB?
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused—are you trying to use _multiple_ databases at once in production? If you just need one database (whether it's shared or not) why can't you just configure it like a regular database?

Comment: I thought that since all applications share only one *model*, each application could have its own database. But your suggestion is a good solution, too. I have no idea how multiple applications the same database. Could you elaborate more about how to configuring it? Thanks.

Comment: In that case, I will use the same `DATABASE` settings for every application, but what about the `User` model defined in each application? Should they be exactly the same? I think so but wonder what if they are not the same? Also, would multiple same model definitions cause any problems?

Comment: In addition, how to deal with multiple migration files of the same `User` model in different applications. Just delete them, retaining only one copy, before `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I don't fully understand your use case. Maybe something like [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants) would help?

Answer (score 1):

1. Django database routers have what you are looking for

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers\

2. Relations do not work cross database

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev//topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases

I recommend trying to keep everything in 1 database initially. Usually when starting out there isn't going to be a need to separate it out.